# Unable to load fragment into activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add the abmob ads to an activity in my android app but the the fragment will not load. When the application load it crash and say's Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment. what is that i have done wrong?

stacktrace

```
    01-06 22:28:02.335    1356-1356/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary, PID: 1356
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:39)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030004
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
            at catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary.HomeActivity$AdFragment.onCreateView(HomeActivity.java:156)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:920)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1206)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2159)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
            at catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:39)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 22:28:04.183    1356-1356/catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1356 SIG: 9
```

AdFragment

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--ads:adUnitId sets the ad unit ID, which is defined in values/strings.xml -->
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Xml Code

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/adFragment"
    android:name="catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary.HomeActivity$AdFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Class

```
package catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import java.util.List;

import catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import database.DatabaseHandler;
import database.DatabaseInfo;
import database.Word;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter tabsPagerAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    private String[] tabsTitles = {"Lesson", "Word"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        initializeDatabase();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        tabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabsTitles) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }

    public void initializeDatabase() {
        List<Word> words = db.getAllWords();

        if (words.size() == 0) {
            DatabaseInfo info = new DatabaseInfo(db);
            info.insertWords();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public static class AdFragment extends Fragment {

        private AdView mAdView;

        public AdFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

            mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();

            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
        }

        /** Called when leaving the activity */
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            if (mAdView != null) {
                mAdView.pause();
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

        /** Called when returning to the activity */
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (mAdView != null) {
                mAdView.resume();
            }
        }

        /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (mAdView != null) {
                mAdView.destroy();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is some error in your xml file `activity_home`. Please post the xml code.

Comment: I posted the xml code

Comment: plz post all of what is in activity_home.xml and the stack trace

Comment: i posted the stack trace and the ad fragment.@petey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HomeActivity class, you've imported `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`, etc. There is a conflict here.

In your XML, you're using `<fragment>`. You need to either change your imports to `android.app.Fragment`, or change XML to:

```
<android.support.v4.app.fragment
    android:id="@+id/adFragment"
    android:name="catchmedia.jamaica.dictionary.HomeActivity$AdFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

If you're using fragments, and want to target devices **before API 11**, you should be using use android.support.v4.app.Fragment. However, if you're only targeting devices running API 11 or above, you can use android.app.Fragment.

Otherwise, there is a conflict between you using Fragment and Fragment from the Android support library.

Answer (score 0):

You should change fragment to android.support.v4.Fragment in your xml file as your AdFragment extends from android.support.v4.Fragment.